# find $\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\ln x - x + 1}{e^{\pi(x-1)} + \sin (\pi x) -1}$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, indeterminate-forms

The answer choices available are:

(a) $\frac{-1}{\pi}$ -------- (b)$\frac{-1}{\pi-1}$

(c) $\frac{-1}{\pi^2}$ -------- (d) undefined

You obviously can't solve the limit straightforwardly, because it gives you an indeterminate form (0/0), right? So I used L'Hôpital's rule, taking the derivative of the numerator and the denominator before plugging in x=1.

Derivative of the numerator: $\frac1x -1$

Derivative of the denominator: $\pi(e^{\pi(x-1)} + \cos(\pi x))$

However, the numerator remains unavoidably equal to zero. Am I doing something wrong, glancing over something really obvious, or are the answer choices wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: well e^pi + 1 = 0, which may get you somewhere

Answer (score 1):

> *Am I doing something wrong?*

No. One may apply L'Hospital's rule *once more* obtaining, as $x \to 1$,
$$
\frac{\left(\frac1x-1\right)'}{\left(\pi(e^{\pi(x-1)} + \cos(\pi x))\right)'}=\frac{-\frac1{x^2}}{\pi^2(e^{\pi(x-1)} -\sin(\pi x))}\to-\frac1{\pi^2}.
$$

Comment: Huh...so, you can continue to apply the rule until you get something workable? Is there any case where that doesn't work (with this type of indeterminate form)?

Comment: @akot717 Yes, you can. Please, have a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule

Comment: I thought that you can only apply the rule for a 0/0 or infinity/infinity form. But I can plug in x=1 after my first application of the rule and get an actual value (0/something =0). Am I going wrong in my thinking somewhere?

Comment: You are allowed to apply it *each time* you have $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$, when the limit *does exist*. It is the case here.

Comment: hmm...I don't want to take up more of your time, but if you plug in X=1 after my first application of the rule you get 

$\frac{0}{\pi (e-1)}$ which is equal to zero.

Comment: You mean $\frac{0}{\pi (e^0-1)}$ which is $\frac{0}{0}$. Isn't it?

Comment: OOOH! I misread the derivative of the "e" term in the denominator as $e^(\pi)^{x-1}$ . My apologies, this makes lots of sense now. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @akot717 You are welcome.